# Why assets (except application.css, applications.js) are not being served in Development mode using require_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, require, assets

I have made all configurations properly to upgrade my Rails app to Rails 3.1.3. Now in my applications.css.erb file and application.js file, I have use the below statements to include these files and the other css and js files

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tinymce-jquery
//= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

application.css.erb

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

But, this is only loading the application.js and application.css through assets.

development.rb

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  # comment out this line:
  # config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

Rails :3.1.3
Ruby: 2.0.0-p247

Please help :)-

Comment: Rajesh, I missed your questions. This is in production right? And you never bothered to READ Rails Guides to know how asset pipeline works?

Comment: I read and I did the upgrade according to that. You didn't answer to my question. This is in development mode. Hope you can see the heading.

Comment: That's the way aset pipeline work. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-debugging-off

Comment: But, unfortunately it's not working. Now, you have any idea why is it not working?

Comment: Did you read what I linked?

Comment: Yes i did. Read my second comment...

Comment: First - you are not reporting a problem with css/js not working, but asking why you have just two links. This is not a valid SO question. Secondly, add your `development.rb` to description

Comment: I do understand that you are not mastering Rails. That's why you are putting links of Rails guides. I will wait if some others could answer my question. Please excuse..

Comment: I suggest you stop downvoting my answers. Read what I wrote, then read again, and LEARN something.

Comment: I think you keep reading only, not doing anything technically. It's better for you to understand the meaning of the question and then put your answer. I know that you are eager for getting points, not for putting valuable answers. I went through many of your answers which you have made copy/paste from other sources, not answering in your own. I hope you have no idea about Asset Pipeline. Then, please excuse.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it was the problem with the order in which the JavaScript files are being loaded using `require_tree.` directive.

When we use `require_tree.` it assumes to load all the js files inside the `app/assets/javascripts` directory in alphabetical order. But in case of javaScript, we can load the files in a particular order so that one file should not conflict with the other regarding any functionalilty.

So, it is better to avoid `require_tree.` directive unless we are using only small number of `js` files. You can explicitly declare each file in the `application.js` manifest file so the order can be controlled.

The common files you are loading can be put in to a separate directory under `app/assets/` and it can be loaded using `require_directory ./separate_directory_name` to load it (iff it has nothing to do with the order).

Thanks :)-